# How to undo all changes that made to a particular file in git?

Tags: git

I have done several changes in a particular file, now I lost the original file, which I required now how to undo all changes made in that file in local machine?

Comment: Could you add `git status` output [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45633394/edit)?

Comment: Can you describe better what you've done since you edited your files til you lost it?

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

```
git checkout -- path of file or file name
```

Comment: Can you paste your whole command. What error are you getting?

Comment: The above one wont work unless you're at the root of your directory and/or the path starting at src is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout path/to/your/file.ext`

**Edit:** If you're weird person who names branches and files the same, use
`git checkout -- path/to/your/file.ext`

If you're not at root of your repo, make sure to update the path accordingly (/, ./, ../, etc)

Comment: This will fail if you have a branch with the same name as the file - you should prefix the file path with `--`.

Comment: That's a pretty uncommon practice IMO to name branches to files.

Comment: I don't think it's a deliberate practice! I can imagine someone creating a branch called "README" and making updates to a "README" file in that branch - without necessarily realising they'd ended up in that position.

Comment: Lol, I guess so.. but still... XD